# download mp3 from url, php

Tags: html, audio, streaming, google-translate

I'm trying to play an audiofile from google translate in an html5 audio element. My code for this is:

```
<script>
    $("#play_button").click(function(){
        $("#memory")[0].play();
    });
</script>

<audio id="memory" preload="auto" style="display: none; ">
    <source src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello">
</audio>
```

which normally would play a voice saying "hello". This works i safari but not in google chrome, where I want it to.

If I "preload" the sound once (loading the url in another tab) and then run this code on my page again, it works. Probably because the audio gets loaded into some cache. (I don't know that much about that...)

Is there anyway to track if the audio is loaded and get the browser to wait for that before trying to play the sound. Or is the solution to download the file to the server and then reference my audio by the new file?

Comment: Please try these... **http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello** and **http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl%3Den%26q%3Dhello**

Comment: I don't see the difference. Both works to load in the browser

Comment: Your query **http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&amp;q=hello**, does not work on google chrome. I'm trying it directly.

Comment: my link isn't http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&amp;q=hello 
I have '&' as the letter. i don't write '&amp;'

Comment: I was looking at the code listing in your question.

Comment: wops, must have been translated when i copied the script from my page to the editor here. My original script only contains '&'. sry

Comment: What happens when you set the preload to "auto"?

Answer (score 0):

The browser interprets html in the same order as it appears in the html file. If you move your script tag below your audio tag, it should load the audio before running the script.

Comment: didn't work unfortunately. Here's my application by the way, http://gustavstromberg.se/sandbox/html5/localstorage/

Comment: @Gustav: I'm wondering if it's related at all to this Chrome bug: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=54ad1a9afc77645f&hl=en Did you try referencing some local files where you can control name/id3 information/etc.?

Comment: at work now bur I will look att that bug later. Yes, I have tried a local file. http://gustavstromberg.se/sandbox/html5/audio/ and it works fine.